# Python smtplib error: getaddrinfo returns an empty list

Tags: sockets, ironpython, smtplib

I have a python application where I am using SMTP to send email. We are using IronPython 2.7

The function call is like this

smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_HOST, SMTP_PORT)

Inside smtplib.SMTP there is self.connect(host, port) where it calls self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout) and returns socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)

The socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout) gives me an error : getaddrinfo returns an empty list

This issue happens intermittently not all the time, so what could be the issue?